# Apache: ScriptAlias as a child of an Alias

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I want a WSGIScriptAlias under an Alias. E.G.

/appA/ returns a static website.

/appA/api/ runs a python module.

I have set up in my httpd.conf

```
Alias  /appA  /source/appA/web/
WSGIScriptAlias /appA/api  /source/appA/bin/api.py/
```

but when browsing to http://localhost/appA/api I get a 404 not found.

Renaming the WSGIScriptAlias to appB/api works.

Any ideas how to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To meet this requirement I used AliasMatch instead of Alias. E.G.

```
AliasMatch  (?i)^/appA^(api)(.*)  /source/appA/web$1
WSGIScriptAlias /appA/api  /source/appA/bin/api.py/
```

AliasMatch uses a regex to map all requests other than the /appA/api request.